# Why are components not marked with @injectable annotation, but services need to be?

Tags: angular

While defining a service / service class in angular, class is decorated with @injectable() decorator.

As per angular guidebook: @Injectable() marks a class as available to an injector for instantiation.

Then why it is not needed while creating a component?

Comment: components are not _injected_ by Angulars DI..

Comment: But Injectors are also responsible for instantiating components.. no?

Answer (score 7):

[From the Angular documentation (emphasis mine):](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injectable)

> Injectors are also responsible for instantiating components like HeroesComponent. So why doesn't HeroesComponent have @Injectable()?
>
> You can add it if you really want to. **It isn't necessary because the HeroesComponent is already marked with @Component, and this decorator class (like @Directive and @Pipe, which you learn about later) is a subtype of @Injectable().** It is in fact @Injectable() decorators that identify a class as a target for instantiation by an injector.

In other words, by marking a class as being a component, directive or pipe, you're implicitly marking them as injectable as well.